# Set up backbone.js environment with webpack

Tags: backbone.js, ecmascript-6, webpack

I've started learning Backbone.js and I'm a little confused with setting up the project. How shoul I set up the Backbone.js environment with Webpack and `npm`? First, I did

```
$ npm init
$ npm i webpack --save-dev
$ npm i webpack-dev-server --save-dev
$ npm i backbone --save-dev
$ npm i jquery --save-dev
$ npm i babel-core
$ npm i babel-loader
$ npm i babel-preset-es2015
```

I had the following in my `webpack.config.js`

```
var config = {
 entry: './main.js',

 output: {
   path:'./',
   filename: 'index.js',
 },

 devServer: {
   inline: true,
   port: 8080
 },

 module: {
   loaders: [
      {
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'babel',

         query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
         }
      }
    ]
  }
}
module.exports = config;
```

and in my `main.js` I had

```
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

but nothing worked. How should I make an initial setup for Backbone with ES6? Also, does Backbone support ES6, or it is rather outdated and deprecated for modern time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you start here: https://github.com/jerrysu/backbone-webpack-example

There's nothing preventing you using Backbone with ES6, though you should read this: http://benmccormick.org/2015/04/07/es6-classes-and-backbone-js/

The first problem I see with your webpack configuration is that your loader is missing a `test` expression (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)